# OPOS PosPrinter.PrintNormal not printing

Tags: c#, opos, pos-for-.net

Below are my code:

```
PosExplorer posExplorer = new PosExplorer();
DeviceCollection receiptPrinterDevices = posExplorer.GetDevices(DeviceType.PosPrinter);
DeviceInfo receiptPrinterDevice = posExplorer.GetDevice(DeviceType.PosPrinter,"SRP2");
PosPrinter printer = (PosPrinter)posExplorer.CreateInstance(receiptPrinterDevice);

printer.Open();
printer.Claim(10000);
printer.DeviceEnabled = true;
printer.PrintNormal(PrinterStation.Receipt, "test print 1");
```

I debug and everything went through without exception, already confirmed also that the printer targeted is the correct one, however the printer is not printing anything. Is there any step that I did wrong? Any guidance is greatly appreciated. Thanks

---

If it helps, My Printer Interface via Ethernet to a specific IP.

Comment: What is the value from `Claimed`? After the call to `printer.Claim(10000);`? and can you print to the printer using the opos set-up program supplied with the printer (if one is supplied)?

Comment: You may also want to check `receiptPrinterDevice.Description` to make sure the DeviceInfo is what you think it is.

Comment: Hi, Claimed value is "TRUE" and the description confirmed that I got the right printer, not a simulator, any thoughts? Thanks..

Comment: Usually the printer OPOS drivers comes with a set-up utility that allows you to set up the logical name (in your case `SRP2`), if so try sending a test print from this util. 
As its a network printer, make sure your firewall is not blocking your program/ port, you could try temporally disabling the firewall and antivirus to see if it prints with them turned off. Your code look fine, although the `receiptPrinterDevices` does not appear to be used.

Comment: Yes, Have tried printing from Util and it works, but somehow still can't print anything through the script..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem appears to be that you are not sending a new line character (`\n`) at the end of your `PrintNormal` string, without it the service object will just buffer the line data, waiting until it sees the `\n` before sending the data to the device.

```
printer.PrintNormal(PrinterStation.Receipt, "test print 1\n");
```

From the POS for .net Documentation on `PrintNormal`

> Newline / Line Feed (10 Decimal)
>
> Print any data in the line buffer, and feed to the next print line. (A carriage return is not required in order to print the line.)

This is because the printer must print one complete line at a time, so it waits until you tell it that you have completed a line before starting to print, this allows you to use 2 or more `PrintNormal` calls for a single line of printout to build up the line data if needed (e.g. in a loop).

I have ran the below code on a networked POS Printer (Tysso PRP-250) and with the \n it prints the line, without it it does not.

```
PosExplorer posExplorer = new PosExplorer();
DeviceInfo receiptPrinterDevice = posExplorer.GetDevice(DeviceType.PosPrinter, "SRP2");
PosPrinter printer = posExplorer.CreateInstance(receiptPrinterDevice) as PosPrinter;

printer.Open();
printer.Claim(10000);
if (printer.Claimed) 
{
    printer.DeviceEnabled = true;
    printer.PrintNormal(PrinterStation.Receipt, "test print 1\n");
    printer.DeviceEnabled = false;   
}
printer.Release();
printer.Close();
```